# How to export all the IIS site and App-pool details to Excel sheet

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PS script where in it will export all the IIS site details to the Excel sheet, but when i try for the IIS App-pool it is not giving the output for all the parameters and the data of app-pool is displaying after the site details but i need the app-pool data parallel to the site data in the same row, please help me to fix this issue.

**Code**

````
Clear-Host
$computers = Get-Content "C:\TEMP\servers.txt" 


    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {
    & {
    Get-Website | Select-Object Name,Id,State,PhysicalPath,
@{n="Bindings"; e= { ($_.bindings | select -expa collection) -join ‘;’ }} ,
@{n="attributes"; e={($_.attributes | % { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ‘;’ }}
Get-IISAppPool | Select-Object Name,Status,CLRVer,PipeLOneMode,StartMode
}
} | Export-Excel -Path C:\users\$env:username\documents\IIS_sites.xlsx```


**Output**
*name           :Test
id             : 2
state          : Started
physicalPath   : C:\Chadrakanth
Bindings       : http 123.com
attributes     : name=2696Test;id=2;serverAutoStart=False;state=1
PSComputerName : AAA
RunspaceId     : 8ec7998e-03e0-47c7-b96a-ffae96260922

Name           : DefaultAppPool
Status         : 
CLRVer         : 
PipeLOneMode   : 
StartMode      : OnDemand
PSComputerName : AAA
RunspaceId     : 8ec7998e-03e0-47c7-b96a-ffae96260922*
````

Comment: The Documentation for the [Get-IISAppPool cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iisapppool?view=win10-ps) says the Output is of the Type [ApplicationPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool?view=iis-dotnet) which does not appear to have a `Status`, `CLRVer` or `PipeLOneMode`. Were you looking for the `State`, `ManagedRuntimeVersion`, `ManagedPipelineMode` properties?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, one more doubt i have, how can i get the IIS site and app-pool details in the same row when i export it to the Excel, as of now the App-pool details are exporting after the IIS site details

Comment: You could save `Get-Website` and `Get-IISAppPool` into variables and then build the Object you want using `[pscustomobject]` or `New-Object` . e.g. `$Website = Get-Website; [pscustomobject]@{id = $Website.id}`

Comment: If possible can you please help me with the Script

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments `Status`, `CLRVer` or `PipeLOneMode` are not available properties and have been replaced with `State`, `ManagedRuntimeVersion`, `ManagedPipelineMode` respectively.

Also since each website is a member of an AppPool, the websites need to be looped over and the appropriate AppPool found for each. Then the properties can be combined into one object using the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator.

```
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\TEMP\servers.txt" 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock {
    # Changed to newer IISAdministration Module to match Get-IISAppPool
    $Websites = Get-IISSite

    foreach ($Website in $Websites) {

        $AppPool = Get-IISAppPool -Name $Website.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            WebsiteName                  = $Website.Name
            WebsiteId                    = $Website.Id
            WebsiteState                 = $Website.State
            WebsitePhysicalPath          = $Website.PhysicalPath
            WebsiteBindings              = $Website.Bindings.Collection -join ';'
            WebsiteAttributes            = ($Website.Attributes | ForEach-Object { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ';'
            AppPoolName                  = $AppPool.Name
            AppPoolState                 = $AppPool.State
            AppPoolManagedRuntimeVersion = $AppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion
            AppPoolManagedPipelineMode   = $AppPool.ManagedPipelineMode
            AppPoolStartMode             = $AppPool.StartMode
        }
    }
} | Export-Excel -Path C:\users\$env:username\documents\IIS_sites.xlsx
```

Comment: With the same Script i am unable to get the Physical path and binding collection details, can you please help me on this

Comment: When i change the command from Get-IISSite to Get-Website i am able to get the Physical path and the Bindings details, but the APP-pool part is not working.

If i keep the same Get-IISSIte i am unable to get the Physical path and Binding details, Please help me on this to fix the issue